# How to make an image rotate towards the cursor while mouse is clicked in javascript, but reset it's rotation o 0 deg when the mouse is depressed

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I can find similar answers but not exact.  I have a map, that I want an image of a car to appear on top of when the mouse is clicked, and rotate so it always points towards the cursor while the mouse button is held down, and then when the mouse is depressed the image of the car disappears and the rotation is reset,  so the next time the mouse is clicked the image appears pointing towards the top of the screen so it can be rotated again.  I am trying to do this in javascript on a leaflet map.

The problem I have is the image does not rotate to point towards the cursor, it rotates unusually, and I can't make it reset to point upwards when the mouse is depressed

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
        crossorigin=""/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-container">
        <header>
            <div class="navitem">
            </div> 
        </header>
        <section class="main-content">
            <div id="gameMap">
            </div>
            <img id="carIcon" style="display: none; z-index:1000;height:80;width:100;" src="carIcon.png"/>
        </section>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="gameMap1.js"></script>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
//Initialize leaflet maps and disable dragging and scrolling
var mymap = L.map('gameMap',{
    renderer: L.canvas()
    }).setView([40.76396283699563, -73.9695559410492], 16);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/satellite-v9',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaGFsNiIsImEiOiJja2Fld2t4bG0wandzMnpwbmp2a24xemdqIn0.OhKsfnxo_9tOpw30fWU-CQ'
}).addTo(mymap);

mymap.dragging.disable();
mymap.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

let gameMapDiv = document.getElementById('gameMap');
let carImage = document.getElementById("carIcon");

//functions to make car image display and disappear
let displayCarImage = function(e){
    carImage.style.display = '';
    carImage.style.position = 'absolute';
    carImage.style.left = clicked_x-52;
    carImage.style.top = clicked_y+70;
    carImage.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
};
let stopDisplayingCarImage = function(e){
    carImage.style.display = 'none';
    carImage.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
    angle = 0
}

//function to calculate angle to rotate the car image by
angle = 0;
function rotateImageAngle(){
    let angle = Math.atan2(-((clicked_y+72) - mouseY), (clicked_x-50) - mouseX)*(180/Math.PI);  
    return angle;
};


//functions to control what happens when mouse is clicked, moved and depressed
var clicked_x = 0;
var clicked_y = 0;
mymap.on('mousedown', function(e) {
    clicked_x =e.containerPoint.x;
    clicked_y =e.containerPoint.y;
    displayCarImage(e);

});

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
gameMapDiv.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
    mouseX = e.clientX; 
    mouseY = e.clientY;
    angleToRotateCar = rotateImageAngle() +'deg'
    carImage.style.transform = 'rotate('+angleToRotateCar+')';
});

mymap.on('mouseup', function(e) {
    stopDisplayingCarImage(e)
});
```

CSS:

```
:root {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS","Trebuchet MS",Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;

}
body, html{
  height:100%;
  width:100%
}

.main-container{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  height:100%;
}
header{
  flex:0 1 auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height:100px;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom:solid 3px black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  z-index: 1000;
}
.navitem{
  height:80%;
}
.main-content{
  flex:0 2 auto;
  height:100%;
}
#gameMap{
  height:90%;
  z-index:900;
  position:relative;
}
footer{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[![https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/0/798.png][1]][1]